# How to pull values from SpreadSheet App from AdWords Scripts. Issues with 'undefined' objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with text values in it that are getting pulled in as undefined. I am pulling these values in a AW Script I wrote in the interface that references a published SS in Google SpreadSheets. Is there a preferred method way to bring in these values?

I have tried:

```
range[i+1][24].toString()
String(range[i+1][24])
range[i+1][24].valueOf()
```

I made sure to check the value of i, and it is pulling in other values from that same row as expected. It just fails to return anything other than undefined when I try to access the 24th column in that row with text in it. I have checked manually to ensure text is in the spreadsheet. Please HALP :(

*Range comes from range = sheet.getRange('A4:X' + count).getValues()

Best,
Jae

Answer (score 2):

When you reference a cell in a range, the index starts with a value of 1.

The array that is returned starts with an index of 0.

```
//sheet.getRange('A4:X'+count).getValues();
var range = sheet.getRange(4,1,count-3,24).getValues();
//cell X4 will be in [0][23]
range[i+1][23]
```

Comment: The problem is that I use range[i+1][3] in the same row, and it returns the value in that cell. I also check the value of i to make sure it corresponds to the correct row....

Comment: figured it out, there was an issue with my range --> I forgot to pull the rightmost columns in.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to change the range() object from A4:X54 to A4:AC54... Stupid mistake on my behalf.

Thanks for the help!